# Are chemical element names capitalized?

Tags: nouns, capitalization, science

Do the names of chemical elements need to be capitalized?

For example, in running text should it be *hydrogen* or *Hydrogen*?

Comment: I have another question related to this. If it's a specific isotope, say U235, do I capitalize uranium then?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

While [chemical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_symbol) always begin with a capital letter, the names of chemical elements do not. In running text, you should be writing *hydrogen*, *oxygen*, *chlorine*, *iron*, etc.

Comment: That is what happens with the physics units: joule, watt, erg, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Elements are common nouns. So the answer is no, they are not capitalized.